# How to install mailparse extension fro PHP on MAMP (Mac)

Tags: php, macos, mamp

I need to install on MAMP Mailparse extension. I have PHP version 7.4.21.

In folder /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.4.21 I run command 'pecl install mailparse' it was successful installation and afterwords I add “extension=mailparse.so” in /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.4.21/conf php.ini and also in /Applications/MAMP/conf/php7.4.21 php.ini.

Afterwards I restart my MAMP and in php info it's doesn't exists mailparse. But when I go to /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.4.21/ or /Applications/MAMP/conf/php7.4.21 and from terminal run 'php -m' I can see that mailparse in the list. And when I run again the installation process in terminal, it's says that it's already installed.

Comment: Is the PHP process that's running your phpinfo page the same one that you actually installed the mailparse extension into?

Answer (score 0):

You have to run the command in /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.4.21/bin

And then add extension=mailparse.so in php.ini

Then restart